# I installed pyyaml via pip, but when I run my Python3 script, I'm not it can't find the module

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pyyaml

I’m on Mac OS X Big Sur.  I installed python3 via brew, and have this version

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.13
```

Pip verison is

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 22.1.1 from /Users/davea/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I want to write a program use the pyyaml module.  I’m told I already installed it

```
$ pip3 install pyyaml
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /Users/david.alvarado/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (6.0)
```

I have this script

```
import pyyaml

arg = sys.argv[0]
with open(arg) as f:
    document = f.readlines()
    print(yaml.load(document))
```

But when I run my program, I’m told pyyaml cannot be found

```
$ python3 convert_yaml_to_json.py ~/Downloads/myfile.yml 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/scripts/convert_yaml_to_json.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyyaml
```

**Edit:** added some output in response to suggestion given

I tried using the full path of Python and I’m told the requirement is already satisfied

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install pyyaml
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (6.0)
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
```

I even tried pip3

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip3 install pyyaml
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named pip3
```

However, when running with the full path it says it can’t find the YAML module

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 convert_yaml_to_json.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/scripts/convert_yaml_to_json.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyyaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyyaml'
```

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: `pip3 --version` ?

Comment: added the pip3 version (22.1.1)

Comment: @Dave I see the problem. Don't you?

Comment: @Dave your `pip3` is not related to your `python3`. Note how `pip3 --version`  refers to "Python 3.8", while `python3 --version` refers to "Python 3.9.13". There is an obvious discrepancy. Your setup seems to have issues. Use the more reliable `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...` notation until you fix your setup.

Comment: I see there's Python 3.8 and Python 3.9, but even when I tried specifying teh full path of Python (added edits with output), I still can't seem to get Python to find pyyaml, although it tells me it is installed when I run the instlal command with the full path.

Comment: @dave The importable package is `yaml` not `pyyaml`. So one needs to install `pyyaml` and then import `yaml`. The installation part seems to be correct now. So next you need to fix your code from `import pyyaml` to `import yaml`. See the [PyYAML doc](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and [ishaant's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation is correct and the module is also in the right directory. The only problem is that in your code you have to change the command `import pyyaml` to `import yaml`

Here is the example; (using your code)

```
import yaml
arg = sys.argv[0]
with open(argv) as f:
     document = f.readlines()
     print(yaml.load(document))
```

It should work correctly now

Comment: Hey dave is your code working correctly now